# How to retrive data with angularjs from node emit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

If I try to retrive data without angularjs from node like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:3000');
socket.on("foo", function(message){
   console.log(message);
      });
```

node.js file:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('update.group', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(message);
    io.emit('foo', message);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

It will work fine...

But how can I now retrive data with angular app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is really how to use socket.io with angular, take a look at [this module](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io)